# how to compare order of the objects of list in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have two lists named gems and gems1 in which I have 16 clones of an object, and they are stored with unique names in lists. Afterward one list gets shuffled. Now I want to compare order of the list s are same or not . How do I do that..??

```
 for(int a=GridHeight;a>0;a--){
                for(int b=0;b<GridWidth;b++)
            {
                     g =  Instantiate(gemprefab, new Vector3 ( b,a, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;

                    g.name= "gem"+ t;
                    g.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;

                    LastGem=g.GetComponent<Gem>();
                    gems1.Add(LastGem);

                    gemComponent = g.GetComponent<Gem>();
                    gems.Add(gemComponent);
    t++;
    }
for(int i = 0; i < gems.Count; i++) {
            Vector3 temp = gems[i].transform.position;
                 randomIndex = Random.Range(0, gems.Count);
            gems[i].transform.position = gems[randomIndex].transform.position;
            gems[randomIndex].transform.position = temp;
            //print (gems[i]);
            //print (gems1[i]);
        }
        }
        void comp() 

        {
              for (int i = 0; i < gems.Count; i++) {
                     for (int j = 0; j< gems1.Count; j++) {

                     if(gems[i].transform.name.StartsWith(gems1[j].transform.name))
                     {
                      break;
                          //print ("gems[i].transform.name");
                          //print ("gems1[i].transform.name");

                     }

        }
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you are trying to do here... Are the names in the transform, or inside a script attached to the GameObjects? Also, if you put the statements print after the break, they will never get called! put them above the break statement

Comment: @  Gaston Claret now you can see i update my snippet in which i have two lists which contains the gameobjects named as g.,one list gets shuffle named as gems. now i wan to compare the these two lists with their object's names. as given  with g.name;

Comment: use contains instead of StartsWith

Comment: @  Alpesh sry but i update my question,i want to compare the order of objectes are same or not

Answer (score 0):

You are close, but you are using too many loops. What you want is to compare each object directly, and since they are of the same length, you can do that in one loop.

UnityScript

```
import System.Collections.Generic;

...

function listsEqual(a : List.<GameObject>, b : List.<GameObject>)//I am assuming that GameObject is the type, but it could be different
{
    for (var i = 0; i < a.Count; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] != b[i])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

C#

```
bool ListsEqual(List<GameObject> a, List<GameObject> b)//I am assuming that GameObject is the type, but it could be different
{
    for (var i = 0; i < a.Count; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] != b[i])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then you can simply implement it like:

```
if (listsEqual(gems, gems1))
{
    //code goes here
}
```

Comment: @ Outlaw Lemur can you please tell me this in c#. hard for me to understand javaScript. please sir

Comment: @user3655131 Check edits, I have both unityscript and C# added

Comment: @ Outlaw Lemur sry but  if (listsEqual(gems, gems1)) condition is running always true..i mean after shuffling the list gems's objects change their respective position.then on comparing the list gems and gems1, it is print finished on button click.why so..??

Comment: @user3655131 The code works fine for me... Can you show what you are doing with it?

Comment: @  Outlaw Lemur i have 15 spheres(clones) in a list i stores them in two arraylist,then a list gems get shuffle as we do in a puzzle,on swap a sphere with other sphere,and spheres has the texture 1 to 15,when i arrange them from 1 to 15 with the help of swap on click now i want to match the position of each spheres in gems with gems1.if it matches.,level2 is load,otherwise nothing happen

Comment: @user3655131 Since the spheres are clones, what would be the feature that tells them apart

Comment: @  Outlaw Lemur 
i only provide them name during they are instantiating with the help of g = Instantiate(gemprefab, new Vector3 ( b,a, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject; g.name= "gem"+ t; g.transform.parent = gameObject.transform; LastGem=g.GetComponent<Gem>(); gems1.Add(LastGem);

Comment: @user3655131 What is the class declaration of `Gem`?